# C# Не получается записать изменённые строки в файл

Tags: c#

Всем привет!
Подскажите, почему не получается записать изменённые строки в файл?

```
            string outputFilename = "output.csv";
            string[] NewFile = File.ReadAllLines("input.csv");
            foreach (string str in NewFile)
            {
                var re = new Regex(@"&.\w*;");
                string str1 = re.Replace(str, "");
                Console.WriteLine(str1);
            }
 
            File.WriteAllLines(outputFilename, NewFile, Encoding.UTF8);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Понял, что записываю не изменения в файл, а прочитанный input в файл.
Попробовал поменять:

```
File.WriteAllLines(outputFilename, str1, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Но говорит, что str1 не существует в текущем контексте

Comment: А где вы что либо записываете или изменяете в файле? Я вижу `string str1 = re.Replace(str, "");`, то есть вы делаете переменную новую и дальше просто ее выводити, как она должна оказаться в файле тогда?

Comment: Я попытался изменить строчку записи в файл File.WriteAllLines(outputFilename, str1, Encoding.UTF8);
изменил параметр NewFile на изменную строку, но VS написал, что str1 не существует в данном контексте

Comment: Вы объявляете str1 внутри цикла, в этом ошибка

Comment: И к чему это должно по вашему привести? `str1` это некая ваша переменная, которая содержит одну строку, допустим вы записываете ее в файл (что у вас не выйдет, ибо не массив), как быть с другими строками? Вы меняете значение строки в массиве, так задавайте это значение этой самой строке, не создавая новых переменных. `string str1` замените на `str`, все, цикл у вас изменит нужное в `NewFile `, который вы в последующем записываете в файл.

Comment: string str1 = string.Empty;
string outputFilename = "output.csv";
string[] NewFile = File.ReadAllLines("input.csv");
foreach (string str in NewFile)
            {
                var re = new Regex(@"&.\w*;");
                str1 = re.Replace(str, "");
                Console.WriteLine(str1);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(outputFilename, str1, Encoding.UTF8);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
Добавил, но теперь компилятор выдал:
Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 2: не удается преобразовать из "string" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>".

Comment: EvgeniyZ, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не перезаписываете ничего в массиве `NewFile`.

1. Используйте цикл `for`, с его помощью можно не только читать данные из массива, но и изменять их.
2. Вместо создания новой переменной `str` записывайте изменение в ваш массив `NewFile`
3. Перепишите название вашего массив `NewFile` в `lowerCamelCase`, т.к. это локальная переменная, а лучше переименуйте её. Например: `inputCsvData`

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputCsvData.Length; i++)
{
    var re = new Regex(@"&.\w*;");
    inputCsvData[i] = re.Replace(inputCsvData[i], "");
    Console.WriteLine(inputCsvData[i]);
}
```

Comment: Но по-хорошему лучше собирать выходные данные в новый массив. Ну, либо прямо сразу писать новые строки в файл. Потому что в общем случае не факт, что в выходном файле будет столько же строк, сколько во входном - обработка разная бывает. Или, например, исходные данные нужно будет несколько раз обработать по-разному - а у вас там уже другие данные лежат - выходные. В общем, лучше не смешивать разные данные (входные и выходные) в одном и том же контейнере.